# Is there an equivalent of "dynamic" type in VB.NET or other way to achieve the same behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a VB.NET class library project. It has a reference to some legacy library with `GuiComponent`

```
 Public Function findById(id As String) As GuiComponent 
        Return session.FindById(id)
 End Function
```

In a new C# project, I want to call this function and I don't want to reference the whole legacy library for it.
So I wrap it with dynamic

```
((dynamic)sth.findById("someId")).select
```

Is there a way to return a dynamic type in VB.NET?

```
Public Function findById(id As String) As Dynamic 'something like this doesn't work
        Return session.FindById(id)
End Function
```

C# equivalent

```
 public dynamic findById(string id) {
     return session.FindById(id);
 }
```

And for sure I don't want to turn off `Option Strict` for the entire project.

Comment: "I don't want to turn off Option Strict for the entire project." - No need to.  Create a partial class code file that includes "Option Strict Off" for the code that needs late binding.  That is as granular as VB gets for using late-binding.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I thought `Option Strict Off` can be used in one class only in VB. Is it possible in C#?

Comment: @hiichaki, "Option Strict" is not a class attribute. It is applied on a source file basis and/or project level basis.  The source file level setting overrides the project level setting.  I originally did not read your question close enough and misunderstood what you are trying to do.  Without verifying if it works, a more complex alternative to the solution proposed by Hans would be to define GuiComponent as inheriting from [DynamicObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No equivalent for `dynamic` in VB.NET, the return type must be `Object`.  There is no support in the CLR either, but all that is really needed here is to convince the C# compiler that "Object" must be interpreted as "dynamic".  In other words, you need to do in VB.NET what the C# compiler does to annotate the return type in the metadata.  That merely takes an attribute, like this:

```
Public Function findById(id As String) As <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Dynamic> Object
        Return session.FindById(id)
End Function
```